# App not showing up on the home screen

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, settings

I happened to download an app and it got completely downloaded (yes, its showing “open” next to the app in AppStore) but somehow its not showing up on the Home screen.

**Points to consider:-**

1. I have not applied any restrictions to download any of the apps in Settings>General>Restrictions.
2. The app is accessible from the AppStore and shows up in the spotlight search only the icon doesn’t show up anywhere no the phone’s screen.
3. Yes I have completely checked in all folders and screen menus, but couldn’t find the app icon.

What steps need to be taken?

Comment: How many _screens_ with apps are present in your iPhone?

Comment: @NimeshNeema there are 7 of them..

Comment: What is the model of your iPhone? Please see if your iPhone is able to add a new Home Screen.

Comment: @NimeshNeema its iPhone 7 plus..new home screen in what way?

Comment: Try doing a hard reset.  If that doesn't work, uninstall the app (`Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Storage` to find the app, tap it, and then you can tap `Delete App`) and then try to reinstall it again from the App Store.

Comment: Go the right most screen. Press and hold an app icon until all the icons start to wiggle, drag the app icon towards the right edge of the screen to add a new home screen.

Comment: Glad to hear!  I'll add it as an answer for you.  Sometimes apps don't install completely or correctly.  Could be a network glitch, bad download, hiccup with the OS, etc.  I'm not sure why it happened, you might never know.

Comment: @fsb But what caused it to work like this??

Comment: Sure you could add that as an answer... it may help others as well! By the way, @fsb how do you guys here on SE know the solutions and reasons for these kinda issues?

Comment: I can't speak for others but for me it's a decade of Mac and 5 years of iOS experience.

Comment: Woah thats amazing! Your knowledge, sure is helping others now, indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen for a number of reasons and you might not know why.

First, do the easy stuff, like you already did.  Search with Spotlight, check for a new Home screen by swiping to the right, and check all your folders.

If those don't work, try a [hard reset](https://www.wikihow.com/Hard-Reset-an-iPhone).  After you restart the iPhone, search for the app again.

If the app is still missing, delete the app and reinstall it from the App Store.  To delete the app (in iOS 11), go to `Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage` and find the app.

Tap the app and on the next screen select `Delete App`.

After the app's deleted, go back to the App Store and redownload the app again.  Hopefully, it will install correctly this time and you'll be able to see it on a Home screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Well its amusing that many times even Hard resets help;)

Comment: I was wondering that would hard resetting in any way damage a “healthy” and newly functioning iPhone??

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 14, Go to Settings > Home Screen  and for "Newly downloaded apps", select Add to Home Screen.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 15, there is a setting to not show newly downloaded apps in the Home Screen and instead just show them in the Apps Library.

Check in the App Library by searching for your missing app. If present you can drag it to the Home Screen. If that was the problem you can revert the setting in Settings > Home Screen & Dock.

Answer (score 1):

Do the Home Screen Layout Reset:

Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Home Screen Layout -> Reset Home Screen

Hope this will others also.

[Source](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/find-missing-apps-your-iphone-0184187/)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I finally found the app where I had embedded it two folders deep. Remember that home screens can have folders within folders.